# Applying a shader to a material turn object pink?

Tags: unity-game-engine

After creating a glow shader in Unity, following this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ALkvh3pJXQ&list=LLaf3bskj3HXKlcOW93L70Xg&index=2&t=272s, I created a sphere, created a material applied the material to the sphere and applied the shader to that material. After that my sphere turn pink, what could be the problem ?

I tried this solution :

"install Lightweight Pipeline from window/package manager

in project panel select : Create/Rendering/Lightweight Pipeline asset

Enter to : Edit/Project settings/Graphics
Add the Lightweight Pipeline asset created before to Scriptable Render Pipeline settings"

But then all of my scene went pink, so I checked If I had render pipeline core package installed in my package manager and I can`t find it in my project packages or in All packages ? Can this be the problem or is there anything else I can do? I do have Lightweight RP and Shader Graph installed in my packages ...
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

2020 solution: for me solution is creating URP pipeline and setting in from project Quality settings.

[image]

If you don't know how to create a URP you can also you can create a new project and observe settings yourself.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, normal shaders doesn't work on PBRs.
Try to go to Edit > Render Pipeline > Upgrade Project Materials to Low (High) Definition Material.

Comment: I only have an option  " update project material to lightweightRp materials" ...

Comment: Yes I updated  Project Materials to lightweightRP materials, but now all of my scene is pink and I cant revert it :/ now I`m really screwed :(

Comment: ok ,  so I had to go to my project settings / graphics/ scriptable render pipeline  and added Lightweight  render pipeline asset, and the pink went away...

Comment: Now when I apply my shader to the material of the object it doesnt turn pink anymore, the shader just has no effect at all ... :/